# Avoiding races when deleting unused Docker images in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a single node Kubernetes cluster. Through a GUI users are able to subscribe to and unsubcribe from various images, subscribing and unscribing instantiates and uninstantiate a container from the selected image.

I've been asked to automate the deletion of unused images.

My problem is that when I try to remove the images, by periodicly running "docker system prune" for example, there is a race between the user resubscribing to the image I'm trying to delete and the deletion.

I've look at using [kubelet Garbage Collection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/) but the flags are deprecated and I've looked at having an aggressive [out of resource handling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/) policy but I think I would end up [evicting end user pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#evicting-end-user-pods) that are being used.

I've tried cordoning the node prior to running "docker system prune" because I thought this would avoid the race but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: If you reach the point where kubelet wants to evict pods, you are far beyond the point at which you should have expanded the capacity of your cluster. If you're thinking about this now, you probably have already reached that point.

Comment: Are you using controllers(deployments/statefulsets/replicasets) for managing users' subscriptions?

Comment: @VASャ Yes - I'm using deployments.

Answer (score 0):

The one solution you could try is to stop kubelet by executing: `systemctl stop kubelet` and than `docker system prune` (remove unused data). After that you start kubelet again.

By doing this you stop any changes on the node while keeping any pods or services' operations. So if someone tries to start a pod with a image that is supposed to be deleted, it won't start until you start kubelet again. It would simply stay in a pending state for a specific node.

Those actions should solve your problem with the race condition with docker images.

Remember however that by doing so you may experience some issues with the metrics collection as cAdvisor is an agent integrated into the kubelet binary.